# Rails: Create a Report System in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, messaging

i'm trying to adapt my messages system in order to be able to use it to send reports to users. For instance, a user might finish a job and he will then receive a private message as a report for that.

The problem is storing the report to my database. A report is not just text. It can have links, or even user generated data, that was previously stored in the db.

My idea was using render_to_string to render a view to a variable and then store it to the database as a new message. However, user generated data and links are a problem, because they are not escaped. Ideally, html tags like 
 should not be escaped, as well as link_to's. However, if there is a <%= user.username %> somewhere in the report, this one should be escaped.

I'm a bit stumbled with that. Do you know of an efficient way to do it ?

Comment: Is there anything wrong with making your template substitutions HTML-safe with `<%= h(user.username) %>`?

Comment: hmm, yeah that could do it you re right. Just using <%=raw for anything else and use h to substitute safely right ?

Comment: Rails 3 does a lot of escaping for you automatically if it's generating HTML output, otherwise it just leaves it as is. In Rails 2 you will need to engage this manually using `h`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally anything that's in HTML mode you can escape with:

```
<%= h(user.username) %>
```

This is the simple "render safe HTML" helper method available to all views. Plain-text does not need to be escaped the same way.